# How to profile individual queries using PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

I've been looking at `SHOW PROFILES`, which seems ideal for what I am doing.

However, I've noticed a [warning that `SHOW PROFILES` is being deprecated](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/show-profiles.html) and that `PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA` should be used instead. In addition, I cannot find any information about how to use `PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA` to benchmark individual session queries in the same manner as `SHOW PROFILES`.